# How to update persistent TStringField.Size from database?

Tags: database, delphi, firebird

A delphi project contains lots of TIBDataSet descendant tables with persistent fields. The underlying database tables changed, and the string field sizes were increased.

Is there a way to automatically update the field sizes, or I have to check and update it manually?

Sorry, I wasn't clear. I would like to change sizes at design time. If I delete and add fields again, it will be updated, but previous modifications will be lost.

Comment: what would you do if the very columns were added or removed in the database? or if some `varchar` column was changed into `integer` column? That is the idea of Persistent fields - to freeze once and forever their declarations in Delphi code. With all good and bad sides of it. Yes, you can read field sizes from the database - but does IBX allow to change their field sizes in `BeforeOpen` event? I don't know... You better remove persistent fields altogether, and just leave them as `public` variables, which you would populate from `AfterOpen` events to real objects using `FieldByName`

Comment: Anyway, DFM files are just text files, normally. So you can make a program that would parse DFM files and match fieldsize property in those with the actual fields in the database

Answer (score 1):

I was successful in adjusting persistent fields with a distributed application that allowed adjusting the length of specific fields.  I would perform a size check query on the adjustable tables returning no data and capture the current sizes and store them.  Before opening the implementation query (TIBDataSet in your case), I would set the persistent field sizes.  The size as you know cannot be adjusted once the query is open.

Comment: ehm... you made two IBX tables per every FB table just ot check field sizes? well, probably would work too...

Comment: I actually used a single query component just after database connection to perform all the size checks.  That was only required once per app launch to set the soft length variables.